# MySQL - Reorganizing One Column/Three Rows into Three Columns/One Row?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm completely new to mySQL and am struggling with the below task.  I have a table, t1, which lists three columns:

```
ITEM    SIZE    COUNT
------------------------
1001    small   11
1001    medium  6
1001    large   34
1002    small   10
1002    large   23
1003    small   81
1003    medium  12
1003    large   38  
...etc...
```

This data goes on for hundreds of tuples.  What I ultimately need to do is reorganize the count like this:

```
ITEM   SMALL   MEDIUM   LARGE
-----------------------------
1001   11      6        34
1002   10      0        23
1003   81      12       38
```

...etc...

Note that Item 1002, Medium size doesn't appear in the first table; hence its value is 0 in the second table.

Any suggestions?  Pointers?  I assume the solution is something like this:

```
SELECT item 'ITEM', if(ITEM=1001 and SIZE=???, SIZE) 'SMALL', ...etc...
FROM t1;
```

But that's as far as I got.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my answer is (for all intents and purposes) the same as @xQbert but using "create table as select" to put the values directly into a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS
  SELECT
    ITEM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE = "small" THEN `COUNT` ELSE 0 END) AS "SMALL",
    SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE = "medium" THEN `COUNT` ELSE 0 END) AS "MEDIUM",
    SUM(CASE WHEN SIZE = "large" THEN `COUNT` ELSE 0 END) AS "LARGE"
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY ITEM;
```

I use backticks around count as its a mySQL keyword and while not required  I habitually backtick any thing that looks like a keyword.

Comment: I habitually back-tick anything that's a reserved word :P  or I rename the table.

Comment: Glad to hear it @Pete it's a basic solution but should work baring any unforeseen issues.

Answer (score 2):

Rextester example: http://rextester.com/VRVPKM75531

Pivot or conditional aggregation (mysql doesn't support pivot)

```
SELECT item 'ITEM'
     , coalesce(max(case when size = 'small' then count end),0) as SMALL
     , coalesce(max(case when size = 'medium' then count end),0) as MEDIUM
     , coalesce(max(case when size = 'large' then count end),0) as LARGE
FROM t1
GROUP BY ITEM
```

If you have multiple counts per item size and you need to "SUM" them you could do that instead of max.  Max in this case implies 1 record per item and size; or you'll lose data.

One can use coalesce when no such record exists to substitute a 0 as needed.  Or not use coalesce  and allow the value to be NULL.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure that's the full answer.  Here's what I got:  (Unfortunately, I can't post the table as a table.  So here's a verbal description...)  'ITEM' is correct.  But every 'SMALL', 'MEDIUM', and 'LARGE' columns have the exact same value:  1 / 2 / 0, respectively.  This is the correct answer for the first tuple, but not the second tuple on down.  Could there be a 'distinct' or 'group by' command or something so that the first tuple's results aren't cloned all the way down the table?  thanks

Comment: the group by item should solve that  here's an example: but maybe im' missing something: http://rextester.com/VRVPKM75531

Comment: or maybe I didn't describe it well.  :)